# In Windows how can we keep an electron js application keep running in task manager

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Am building an electronjs application so in windows operating system how can i retain or get the session back even after closing application and reopen application?

In more detail: when user gets signed into the application and closes the application and reopen the application he should not be signed off and the application should be running in the task manager, can some help me in this scenario

Comment: Hello!  You may want to include some details on what have you tried so far to solve this problem, or where you've hit a roadblock in your progress here.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app

> Event: 'window-all-closed'
> Emitted when all windows have been closed.
> If you do not subscribe to this event and all windows are closed, the default behavior is to quit the app; however, if you subscribe, you control whether the app quits or not. If the user pressed Cmd + Q, or the developer called app.quit(), Electron will first try to close all the windows and then emit the will-quit event, and in this case the window-all-closed event would not be emitted.

So by default when all windows are closed the app is terminated.  However, as it states, to change this default behavior, all you should have to do is bind to the event and then do not quit the app.

```
const { app } = require('electron')
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  //app.quit()
})
```

*Obvious disclaimer: the quote and code snippet used and modified were copied from the linked source.